# HTML put two div side by side

Tags: html, css

How can I put two div side by side with CSS like shown on the image down here?

Eventually I'd like the div on the left to be scrollable, but it's not necessary.

The most important thing I need is to put them side by side.

[image]

Comment: Don't expect us to write code for you, show some effort or that you actually tried looking for a solution before posting a question.

Comment: While it's possible to do a two-column layout, it may not be possible to have them match height *and* have one that scrolls using only CSS. Usually the height on the shorter one is faked in some fashion and the taller one is as tall as is possible given its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your divs into common parent, and then you have to use css. For the left div, add `style="float: left"`. For the second one write `style="float: right"`.

Comment: Flexbox is a more elegant solution, however, flexbox is not supported by IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. 'Better' is a bit bluntly and downvoting a valid solution is... well... at least disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Side by side divs:

```
display: inline-block;
```

//add this to both divs

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Scrollable div:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

//add this to the left div

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

example:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/90h5c20x/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both divs inside another div and apply the flexbox to the wrapper

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="div1">
      <!-- div code here -->
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
      <!-- div code here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

This works smoother than inline-block and floats and is mobile responsive. It will also allow the scrolling for the first div.

Comment: This does not work in IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is cool and very elegant, but it simply does not work in a production environment (IE9 and lower) without any fixes/hacks. Therefore I am providing this working cross-browser answer.

Here is your HTML:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    <!-- div code here -->
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <!-- div code here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {display: table;}
.div1, .div2 {display: table-cell;}
```

And here is the working code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVMprO

Here is the code with overflow: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNoXBJ

Comment: nop, not working, where is the overflow suppose to happen ? ... you need an extra wrpper eventually : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNoXBJ even if you use flex ....

Comment: Nice solution for the overflow! I thought the overflow was 'optional' so I intentionally left it out to keep things clean.